# Change size of Character in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to change the size of the 1,2 and 3 numbers to tiny or small, but when applied to the code they do not change on the chart.

```
// Candle Type Pine Script
study("Candle Type", overlay=true, precision=0)

// check for candle type 1 (inside candle) and plot an identifier
barResult1 = high <= high[1] and low >= low[1]
plotchar(barResult1, title="Bar Type 1 Label", char="1", size=size.tiny, show_last =  50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)

// check for candle type 2up and plot an identifier
barResult2u = (high > high[1]) and (low >= low[1])
plotchar(barResult2u, title="Bar Type 2u Label", char="2", size=size.tiny, show_last = 50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)

// check for candle type 2d and plot an identifier
barResult2d = (low < low[1]) and (high <= high[1])
plotchar(barResult2d, title="Bar Type 2d Label", char="2", size=size.tiny, show_last = 50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)

// check for candle type 3 (engulfing candle) and plot an identifier
barResult3 = high > high[1] and low < low[1]
plotchar(barResult3, title="Bar Type 3 Label", char="3", size=size.tiny, show_last = 50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the sizes are set to `size.tiny` in your code. Change them and it will work.

```
//@version=4
study("My script", overlay=true)

// check for candle type 1 (inside candle) and plot an identifier
barResult1 = high <= high[1] and low >= low[1]
plotchar(barResult1, title="Bar Type 1 Label", char="1", size=size.tiny, show_last =  50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)

// check for candle type 2up and plot an identifier
barResult2u = (high > high[1]) and (low >= low[1])
plotchar(barResult2u, title="Bar Type 2u Label", char="2", size=size.small, show_last = 50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)

// check for candle type 2d and plot an identifier
barResult2d = (low < low[1]) and (high <= high[1])
plotchar(barResult2d, title="Bar Type 2d Label", char="2", size=size.normal, show_last = 50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)

// check for candle type 3 (engulfing candle) and plot an identifier
barResult3 = high > high[1] and low < low[1]
plotchar(barResult3, title="Bar Type 3 Label", char="3", size=size.huge, show_last = 50, location=location.abovebar, color=#0080FF)
```

[image]